# How to change the color of footer bar on android mobile browser devices?

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, mobile, meta-tags

I'm wanting to change the color of the footer bar on a mobile website I'm creating.

The way to do this for the header address bar on mobile Chrome websites is by adding this piece of code inside the `<head>`

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#bada55">
```

Is there something similar for the footer bar?

[image]